# Regex for string such that adjacent characters are different

Tags: regex

How do I write regular expression for a string containing `[a-z]` characters, such that no pair of adjacent characters is the same?

Example:

Valid strings:

```
abcd
qwerty
z
try
except
public
```

Invalid strings:

```
class
buzz
agreed
```

Answer (score 4):

This won't match the strings which has at-least two contiguous repeated characters.

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)[a-z]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nG2xO7/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can this regex that will match whole words and will only check if there are no identical adjacent letters (not checking any other symbols):

```
\b(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1[a-z]*)[a-z]+\b
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV9mB9/1).